# Anyone can you help me about SQL Query (GROUP WHERE)

Tags: mysql

Database:

Orders:

```
| orders_id  |   shop_id   |mode|
|:-----------|------------:|---:|
| 1          |        1001 |   1|
| 2          |        1001 |   1|
| 3          |        1001 |   2|
| 4          |        1003 |   1|
| 5          |        1004 |   1|
| 6          |        1004 |   2|
```

Show: total = total_mode_1 * 20 + total_mode_2 * 10;

```
| shop_id    |total Mode 1|total Mode 2|total|
|:-----------|-----------:|-----------:|----:|
| 1001       |           2|           1|   50|
| 1004       |           1|           1|   30|
| 1003       |           1|           0|   20|
```

I have data struct. Can you query this ? I try some time but not worked.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query based on the formula you gave,

```
select shop_id, 
    count(case when o_mode = 1 then 1 end) as tm_1,
    count(case when o_mode = 2 then 1 end) as tm_2, 
    count(case when o_mode = 1 then 1 end)*20 + count(case when o_mode = 2 then 1 end)*10 as total  
from order_test 
group by shop_id 
order by total desc;
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+------+-------+
| shop_id | tm_1 | tm_2 | total |
+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1001 |    2 |    1 |    50 |
|    1004 |    1 |    1 |    30 |
|    1003 |    1 |    0 |    20 |
+---------+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can apply `asc` or `desc` on `order by` clause, based on your requirement. Obviously, there is redundancy in query. But I don't think we can get rid of it, as renamed column can't be used in `select`.

**Note:** `o_mode` = `mode`. I've just renamed column.

Answer (score 3):

In mysql it's easier when you use local variables:

```
SELECT
    shop_id,
    SUM(@tm1 := IF(`mode`=1, 1, 0)) AS tot_mode_1, 
    SUM(@tm2 := IF(`mode`=2, 1, 0)) AS tot_mode_2,
    SUM(@tm1 * 20 + @tm2 * 10) AS total
FROM orders 
GROUP BY shop_id
ORDER BY total desc
```

What we do is check for each row if mode is 1 or 2 and store to local var, this local var we need later to count total

result will be:

```
shop_id     tot_mode_1  tot_mode_2  total
1001        2           1           50
1004        1           1           30
1003        1           0           20
```